# Requesting another server for file exist in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a condition where I need to check for the file in another server, if that file exists I need to delete from the current server. Can any body help me.

Comment: Please provide more detail, how you need to access this file (http, ssh ?) to test its existence.

Comment: use SSH, http is not for dealing with File System

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write a ruby script and do something along the line with:

```
require "open-uri"

file_name = "file.name"

begin
  file = open("http://www.example.com/#{file_name}")
  File.delete("path_to" + file_name)
  p "File #{file_name} deleted"
rescue
  p "File not found"
end
```

Comment: can File.delete will delete the file in another server. If so then what about security?

Comment: No. But it can delete from current server. That is what was asked.

Comment: Ahhhh. Sorry, programers logic :) Your question is phrased incorrectly. Answer above by Adrian Serafin is correct then.

Answer (score 3):

You can place a  script on another server and ask it in restful way to perform that tasks for you:

```
http://another.server/exists/:file_name
http://another.server/delete/:file_name
```

but you will have to think about security aspects of this solution.

Also take a look on executing remote commands via ssh: http://bashcurescancer.com/run_remote_commands_with_ssh.html. Combined with [using ssh "without password"](http://www.csua.berkeley.edu/~ranga/notes/ssh_nopass.html) it can be acceptable solution to run command line program that run what you need.